# What is the effect of the capacitor on the input power and torque of permanent split capacitor (PSC) single phase induction motor?

Tags: capacitor, motor, torque, induction, phase

I need to know the effect of the capacitor on the input power and torque of a permanent split capacitor (PSC) single phase induction motor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without it, the motor is likely to sit there, stalled.

Comment: i want to know the effect as the value of the capacitor increases